# How can i make user post public in the firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I relatively new to firebase real-time database. I am trying to make `userPosts` publicly available and the user who created the post should be able to edit and view their own posts. I am struggling to make the post public and only the user who owns the post should edit it. Bellow, is the firebase database rules. When I try to simulate it to edit `userPosts`, it gets denied. Don't know why it happens.
Sorry for my bad English. Let me know if I need to provide more information.

```
{
 "rules": {
   "users": {
     "$userId": {
       "profile" :{
         ".read": "$userId == auth.uid",
         ".write": "$userId == auth.uid",
       }
   }
}, 
    "userPosts":{
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$userId": {
        //".write": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId",
      }
    },

  }
}
```

this is the image of firebase simulate image
[Firebase simulate details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx70W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your simulator, your UID is `d62cf9b9-265b...`, but your edit is at `userPosts/userId` literally.

Your edit should be at `userPosts/d62cf9b9-265b...`.

Comment: That is a typo in the question, sorry for that. I wanted to make ``` userOwnedPosts``` public for other users to see the post, created by another user. I am struggling to understand how firebase database rules work. When I try to simulate it on firebase it always gets denied.

Comment: @Noman I see. Your rules look fine. If you're still having trouble with the simulator, click on the "Details" button and see what it says, maybe post a screenshot of your simulation here.

Comment: I have corrected the typo and changed `userOwnedPost` to `userPosts`. Already done that, and yes, I simulating an edit to `userPosts/{uid}`. this, did not solved the issue.

Comment: I have provided an image of the firebase simulate details.

Comment: Ahh, I did not think of that. I thought if I did it like this `userPosts/userId` was correct, but was wrong. Thanks for the help and your time :).

Comment: @Noman ...but then, how would you refer to `userPosts/userId` literally? :P You're welcome